# Laravel removes Fideloper while installing Stripe leading to :n Application.php line 735: Class Fideloper\Proxy\TrustedProxyServiceProvider" not found

Tags: php, laravel, xampp, stripe-payments, laravel-8

I would like to integrate Stripe to my Laravel 8 project. But the Composer always removes Fideloper during the installation process (`composer require stripe/stripe-php`). And this leads to an error:

> In Application.php line 735: Class Fideloper\Proxy\TrustedProxyServiceProvider" not found

when trying to start Laravel.
What could I do?